# Set different options in lightning-combobox in for:each template

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I have a component that lets you select different troubleshooting scenarios that have specific outcomes related to them. The logic is as follows:

- User selects a scenario in a combobox.
- Different outcomes are loaded in another 'Outcome' combobox based on the selection.
- The user selects an outcome.
- The user then has the choice of adding more scenarios/outcomes by clicking a button.
- If they do, another two comboboxes are added.
- Finally, the list is saved in an org.

The problem that I have is that the first Scenario combobox is loaded with a general set of data, but the Outcome combobox is loaded based on the selection of the Scenario combobox. The number of inputs is dynamic, two more are added each time the users clicks a button, so the options array should not have the same values for each outcome combobox generated.

html

```
<template for:each={steps} for:item="step">
    <div key={step.Id}>
        <lightning-combobox
        data-item={step.Id}
        label="Select Troubleshooting Scenario"
        name="scenario"
        value={scenarioValue}
        onchange={handleScenarioChange}
        options={scenarioOptions}>
        </lightning-combobox>

        <lightning-combobox
        data-item={step.Id}
        label="Select Outcome"
        name="outcome"
        value={outcomeValue}
        onchange={handleOutcomeChange}
        options={outcomeOptions}>
        </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
</template>
<lightning-button label="Add another step"onclick={handleAddAnotherStep}></lightning-button>
```

js

```
@track steps = [{ Id : 1 }];
stepsCounter = 1;
scenarioOptions = [];
outcomeOptions = [];
scenarioValue;
outcomeValue;

@wire(getScenarios) {
    allScenarios({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.scenarioOptions = [];
        this.scenarioOptions = data.map(data => ({ label: data.Name, value: data.Id }));
    } else if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

handleScenarioChange(event) {
    this.scenarioValue = event.target.value;
    this.callGetOutcomes(event.target.value);
}

callGetOutcomes(recordId) {
    getOutcomes({ scenarioId: recordId }).then((data) => {
        this.outcomeOptions = [];
        this.outcomeOptions = data.map(data => ({ label: data.Name, value: data.Id }));
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

handleOutcomeChange(event) {
    this.outcomeValue = event.target.value;
}

handleAddAnotherStep() {
    this.stepsCounter += 1;
    this.steps.push({ Id: this.stepsCounter });
}
```

I have no idea how to solve this. Binding {outcomeOptions} and loading them with values will not work, because these options are dependant of the scenario loaded. Any ideas of how to approach this of it is even possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved by creating a new lwc component with the lightning-comboboxes that handles its own events and data. That way you can use it inside a for:each and have them operate independently from each other.

```
<template for:each={steps} for:item="step">
<div key={step.Id}>
    <c-combobox-child-component 
       data={step.Id}>         
    </c-combobox-child-component>
</div>
</template>
```

This way each component can have their own option list.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include more detail?  What do you mean by "having the inputs in a different LWC"?  Please [edit] your answer.

Comment: done. thank you